# Prime numbers recursion

Tags: java, recursion, iterator

I need to iterate  and print prime numbers. This code works fine but if number isn't prime it prints -1. Is there way to remove -1s?

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
    if (position >= end) {
        return false;
    } else {
        position++;
        return true;

}
}

@Override
public int next(int a) {

        for(int i=2;i<a;i++) {
            if(a%i==0)

                return -1;

         }
        if(a==0||a==1) return -1;
        return a;
    }
```

in main i need to print it in this way that's why i need int method that return prime number

```
while(hasNext()){
        System.out.println(next(position));
    }
```

Comment: There is no recursion here and it's also not very clear what are you trying to do: are you trying to return a prime number < a ?

Comment: What language is this, java? Please tag your question accordingly. And where is the recursion in your code?

Comment: @alfasin yes I'm trying return prime number

Comment: @Bergi yes it's java. for is my base case

Comment: "I'm trying return prime number " - then return 2. Otherwise you should be clearer on the requirements.

Comment: @alfasin I edited my question

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni Actually I'm not sure

Comment: Ok that's my final comment here: "I need to iterate and print prime numbers" - is NOT a clear requirement. you can print "2,3" and it will answer that "requirement". Saying that the "code works fine" but it doesn't print what you expect means that the code doesn't work. Be clear, state your goal, example for input and expected output. Once you do that people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method that calls itself is said to be recursive.

Here is the code to get Prime numbers  in recursive manner

```
public class Prime {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        int res = isPrime(i, i -1);
        if(res == 1){
            System.out.println(i +" is a prime number");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(i +" not a prime number");
        }
    }
}

static int isPrime(int a, int div) {
    if(div <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a % div == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return isPrime(a, div-1);
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Recursive code for Prime Number.

Returns the number if it is prime

```
public class Prime 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       {
         if (isPrimeNumber(i) == 1)
         {
            System.out.println(i+ " is a prime Number");
         }
       }
    }


    public static int isPrimeNumber(int i) {
        int factors = 0;
        int j = 1;

        while(j <= i)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                factors++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        int flag = 0;
        if(factors == 2){
            flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;

  }
}
```

Comment: I need to return integer

Comment: thank you very much but I only need a int method that returns prime number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is to print only the prime numbers and

- // You need to return a value from the function.
  In this case, handle the -1 case in the caller function i.e
   `if(next(a)!=-1)` => print a is prime.
- // You just want to print the prime numbers and can modify your function

  - Rename the function as isPrime and return boolean (true for prime and false otherwise).
  - `if(isPrime(a)==true)` => Print a is prime.

Comment: Note: Your question is not clear and hence we might not be able to give you an exact solution for your requirement.

Comment: Note: you're right and hence you shouldn't submit a "guess" as a solution :)

Comment: The question asks for a solution which is provided by both the ways. So both options are equally correct. The only reason for submitting the solution was to help the user :)